# For permutation matrices, if $\mathbf{QA}=\mathbf{AR}$, does $\mathbf Q=\mathbf R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Suppose $\mathbf A$ is a real symmetric matrix with at least one non-zero entry off the diagonal (think of it as the adjacency matrix of a non-empty graph), and $\mathbf Q$ and $\mathbf R$ are both [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

I suspect it is the case that if $\mathbf{QA}=\mathbf{AR}$, then we can deduce that $\mathbf Q=\mathbf R$, but I have no idea how to prove it.

I'm asking here in case it's a standard fact which is known, but I can't seem to find anything like it in any textbooks.

Comment: This is certainly false if $A=0$ (which is a real symmetric matrix!)

Comment: @5xum Of course, I suppose even if $\mathbf A$ is the identity. In general I am thinking of $\mathbf A$ as the adjacency matrix of some graph, let me amend my question to reflect this.

Comment: If $A$ is the identity, then $QA=AR$ certainly implies $Q=R$. This implication does not exist if $A=0$. Also, the zero matrix *is* an adjacency matrix of a graph...

Comment: @5xum Of course, let me add non-zero to the question.

Comment: If $n\ge 3$, then any $n \times n$ matrix which is zero apart from a single non-zero entry on the diagonal is a counterexample.

Comment: @TonyK That is true, I've amended the question to reflect this.

Comment: This is moving the goalpost further, but there are still easy counterexamples to be had.  You can think of one using block matrices now where $Q = \begin{bmatrix}Q_1&0\\0&Q_2\end{bmatrix}$ and so on where although $Q_1=R_1$ and $A_1$ has off diagonals and that $Q_2\neq R_2$ using the same counterexamples for $A_2$ as before

Comment: *In general* one should be highly skeptical of multiplication on the left being equivalent to multiplication on the right.  These are very different actions.

Comment: Even if $A$ is invertible, your question would be "does conjugation by $A$ fix every permutation matrix?", to which the answer is still no. In terms of graph theory, you're asking "let $G$ be a graph, let $f$ and $g$ be permutations of the vertices of $G$ such that the weight of the edge from $u$ to $v$ is always the same as the weight of the edge from $f(u)$ to $g(v)$. Must $f = g$?". The answer to this is no for all sorts of reasons. One example: let $G$ be the square $Q_2$ (without loops), let $f$ be the identity and let $g$ be the permutation swapping opposite vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Take $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ and let $$\begin{align}Q&=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0&0\\0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\\ R=I&=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Then, $AR=A=QA$, however $Q\neq R$.

Comment: Yes! Indeed, the top-left $2\times 2$ sub-matrix can be anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily the case even if you require $\ \mathbf{A}\ $ to be non-singular.  If
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}&=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1}\ ,\\
\mathbf{Q}&=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}\ , \text{and}\\
\mathbf{R}&=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0}\ne\mathbf{Q}
\end{align}
for instance, then $\ \mathbf{A}\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{R}\mathbf{A}\ .$ More generally, if $\ \mathbf{A}\ $ is an $\ n\times n\ $ permutation matrix corresponding to a product of one or more disjoint transpositions, then $\ \mathbf{A}\ $ will be a symmetric, non-singular matrix with at least two non-zero off-diagonal elements.  Now if $\ \mathbf{Q}\ $ is *any* $\ n\times n\ $ permutation matrix whose corresponding permutation is not self-conjugate under conjugation by the permutation corresponding to the matrix $\ \mathbf{A}\ ,$ then $\ \mathbf{R}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\ne\mathbf{Q}\ $ will be a permutation matrix that satisfies the equation $\ \mathbf{A}\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{R}\mathbf{A}\ .$

Comment: Your $\mathbf{Q}$ is not a permutation matrix. Presumably, either the top or the bottom row should be $0\,1\,0$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what it should have been (and is, now that I've corrected it).  Thank you for picking up the error.